# Prove that for each integer $n \ge 2$ there exists a prime number $p$ dividing $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Let $c \ge 1$ be an integer. Define a sequence of positive integers by $a_1 = c$ and $$a_{n+1}=a_n^3-4c\cdot a_n^2+5c^2\cdot a_n+c$$ for all $n\ge 1$.
Prove that for each integer $n \ge 2$ there exists a prime number $p$ dividing $a_n$ but none of the numbers $a_1 , \ldots , a_{n -1}$